# select a tab on mouseover using jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs, mouseover

I have tabs in the form of

```
                <li><a href="#tabsctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c3a47fcd_015c_4096_ad26_59b99086ef40_ctl00-1">
                    tab1</a> </li>

                <li><a href="#tabsctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c3a47fcd_015c_4096_ad26_59b99086ef40_ctl00-2">
                    tab2</a> </li>

                <li><a href="#tabsctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c3a47fcd_015c_4096_ad26_59b99086ef40_ctl00-3">
                    tab1</a> </li>

                <li><a href="#tabsctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c3a47fcd_015c_4096_ad26_59b99086ef40_ctl00-4">
                    tab3</a> </li>

                <li><a href="#tabsctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c3a47fcd_015c_4096_ad26_59b99086ef40_ctl00-5">
                    tab4</a> </li>

                <li><a href="#tabsctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c3a47fcd_015c_4096_ad26_59b99086ef40_ctl00-6">
                    tab5</a> </li>

                <li><a href="#tabsctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c3a47fcd_015c_4096_ad26_59b99086ef40_ctl00-7">
                    tab7</a> </li>

                <li><a href="#tabsctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_c3a47fcd_015c_4096_ad26_59b99086ef40_ctl00-8">
                    tab8</a> </li>

    </ul>
```

I want the tab to be selected on mouseover of the tab and the contents must be visible on the same.
I tried changing the tabIndex property to 0 and set aria-selected to true. But doesnt look like it is of any help.
I really have no clue as i am new to jquery.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: _"the contents must be visible"_ - What contents? And what does "selected" mean exactly?

Comment: Can you please provide your jquery or javascript  code?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('JQUERY PATH TO TABS li a').mouseenter(function(){
        this.click();
    });
```

Comment: +1. This was my best guess at what the OP was trying to ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
$("li").hover(function(){
 $(this).trigger('click');
 });
```

Comment: Hi..  Thank youu all for the response :) 
The following worked for me..I was using a jquery tab container which i forgot to mention.

$($div).tabs("select", 1);

Answer (score 0):

Thank youu all for the response :) The following worked for me..I was using a jquery tab container which i forgot to mention. $($div).tabs("select", 1);

Answer (score 0):

```
  Enjoy with simple code............  
  $('.Class Name').mouseenter(function(){
            this.click();
        });
```

Comment: Please explain your answer